# Eigenvalues of $A^2 = I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with $n>1$ and $A^2 = I_n$, where $I_n$ denotes the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

a) What are the possible eigenvalues of $A$? (I know that two eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$, i.e. if $A$ is the positive or negative $n\times n$ identity matrix, but are there others?)

b) Is $A + 15I_2$ invertible? Why or why not? I'm going to say yes, because $-15$ cannot be an eigenvalue so $\det(A+15I_2)$ will not be $0$? Not sure.

c) Give an example of a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ with $A^2 = I_2$, but $A$ does not equal $I_n$ and A does not equal $-I_2$. I found one, $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math on MSE see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What you have here is called an *Involutory matrix*, it has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: As a proof, let $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of A and $x \neq 0$ respective eigenvector, then

$Ax = \lambda x \Leftrightarrow A^{-1}A x= \lambda A^{-1} x \Leftrightarrow x = \lambda A x \Leftrightarrow x = \lambda^2 x \Leftrightarrow (1-\lambda^2)x = 0$
from which we can conclude $\lambda =\pm 1$

Comment: I know your problem is done, but for additional reading you may want to look up minimal polynomials and their relationship to characteristic polynomials.  Also, it could be useful to know that $A$ could potentially represent any reflection, such as $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ which reflects about the line $y=x$, or the example you gave which reflects about the line $y=0$, or others. Not only $2\times 2$ but that's easiest to write as you know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A^2=I_n$ and $v\neq 0$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then we have:
$$Av=\lambda v\implies A^2v=A\lambda v\implies I_nv=\lambda(Av)\implies v=\lambda^2v\implies v(\lambda^2-1)=0$$
since $v\neq 0$, we have $\lambda =\pm 1$, which is what you have.

For part (b), that is a good answer on your part, and the fact that $-15$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ follows from the above proof.

For part (c), that is a good example.